# Laravel PayPal tutorial into real world scenario

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5.4

I have been following the tutorial on http://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-54

I'm now trying to use this in an an application i'm developing but i'm quite new to PHP/Laravel so trying to get these paypal functions into my own Controller/forms that I have already built.

I have a controller "BookingsController" which has a form on ../bookings/create that when the EU presses the submit button it will enter the info into the DB, which works perfect, and then runs the PayPal bits to take the EU to the PayPal checkout which is where i've come unstuck.

My Controller:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Market;
use App\Stall;
use App\Booking;
use Auth;
use GuzzleHttp\Transaction;

class BookingsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
      $market = Market::where('is_active', true)->orderBy('name')->pluck('name','id');
      $stall = Stall::pluck('name','id')->all();
      return view ('bookings.create', compact('market','stall'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'email',
          'address' => 'required',
          'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        //Uncomment the below line to test form values
        // return $request->all();
        $booking = new Booking;
        $booking->name = $request->input('name');
        $booking->email = $request->input('email');
        $booking->address = $request->input('address');
        $booking->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $booking->market_id = $request->input('market_id');
        $booking->stall_id = $request->input('stall_id');
        $booking->itemtype = $request->input('itemtype');
        $booking->clothesrail = $request->input('clothesrail');
        $booking->businessname = $request->input('businessname');
        $booking->insurance = $request->input('insurance');

        //Get the stall cost
        //$stallPrice = Stall::pluck('cost')->where('id', '=', $booking->stall_id);
        $stallPrice = 15;

        //Check if the user is logged in. If so then submit the user_id
        if (Auth::check())
        {
          $booking->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        }


        //return $stallPrice;
        //$booking->save();

        //Redirect user based on logged in session_status
        if (Auth::check())
        {
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Stall Booked!');
        }
        return redirect('/confirm')->with('success', 'Stall Booked!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $booking = Booking::find($id);
      return view('bookings.edit')->with('booking', $booking);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
      ]);

    $booking = Booking::find($id);
    $booking->name = $request->input('name');
    $booking->email = $request->input('email');
    $booking->address = $request->input('address');
    $booking->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $booking->market_id = $request->input('market_id');
    $booking->stall_id = $request->input('stall_id');
    $booking->itemtype = $request->input('itemtype');
    $booking->clothesrail = $request->input('clothesrail');
    $booking->businessname = $request->input('businessname');
    $booking->insurance = $request->input('insurance');

    //Check if the user is logged in. If so then submit the user_id
    if (Auth::check())
    {
      $booking->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    }

    $booking->save();

    return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('success', 'Booking Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $booking = Booking::find($id);
      $booking->delete();

      return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('success', 'Booking Removed');
    }
}
```

My View with the form:-

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Book a Stall</div>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Clothes Rails are not provided. You will need to provide this yourself.</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
              {!!Form::open(['action' => 'BookingsController@store','method' => 'POST'])!!}

                @if (Auth::check())
                {{Form::bsText('name',Auth::user()->name)}}
                {{Form::bsText('email',Auth::user()->email)}}
                {{Form::bsText('address',Auth::user()->address)}}
                {{Form::bsText('phone',Auth::user()->phone)}}
                @else
                {{Form::bsText('name','',['placeholder' => 'Name'])}}
                {{Form::bsText('email','',['placeholder' => 'Email'])}}
                {{Form::bsText('address','',['placeholder' => 'Address'])}}
                {{Form::bsText('phone','',['placeholder' => 'Phone'])}}
                @endif

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('market_id', 'Date:') !!}
                  {!! Form::select('market_id', $market , null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('stall_id', 'Type of stall:') !!}
                  {!! Form::select('stall_id', $stall , null, ['id' => 'stall_id', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                </div>
                {{Form::bsText('itemtype','',['placeholder' => 'Type of items to sell'])}}
                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('clothesrail', 'Clothes Rail?:') !!}
                  {!! Form::label('clothesrail', 'Yes') !!}
                  {!! Form::radio('clothesrail', 1, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                  {!! Form::label('clothesrail', 'No') !!}
                  {!! Form::radio('clothesrail', 0, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('businessname', 'Business Name:') !!}
                  {!! Form::text('businessname', null, ['id' => 'businessname', 'class'=>'form-control hidden'])!!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'Public Liability Insurance??:') !!}
                  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'Yes') !!}
                  {!! Form::radio('insurance', 1, ['id' => 'insurance', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                  {!! Form::label('insurance', 'No') !!}
                  {!! Form::radio('insurance', 0, ['id' => 'insurance', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                </div>
                {{Form::bsSubmit('Submit')}}
              {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

NOTES:

- The submit button calls the "store" method in the controller
- I can't get the Stall Price to pull from the user's selection into the variable but I'll deal with that later as I can fix that, i'm just working with a fixed value variable to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
$stallPrice = Stall::pluck('cost')->where('id', '=', $booking->stall_id);
```

**TO**

```
$stallPrice = DB::table('your_stall_table')->find($booking->stall_id)->cost;
```

Here, you need to `your_stall_table` with your actual stall table name.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that! Now I just need to get it to process the payment!

Comment: Without any detail, can't help you

Comment: See above, I'm using the tutorial which has it's own controlller and view/form but I need my form to be processed by PayPal using the solution in the tutorial and setting the variables for the PayPal payment

Comment: @Luke: I'll check this and will try to explain how this work for you...

Comment: Would just adding all of the PayPal Controller code into the Bookings controller work?